# Hadoop job name is not reflected in JobTrcker console

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hadoop-partitioning

I have mentioned the job name in driver class as "  job = new Job(conf, "Partitioning Even Odd Numbers"); " . And i have changed the job name " custom job" . But the job name is not reflected when run mapreduce program in jobtracker console.

Comment: have you rebuild the jar?

Comment: yes, i rebuild new jar every time before deploying. but it is not showing 2 reducer partitioners